# How to configure Search Module in Joomla to search in specified category?

Tags: search, joomla, module

Hey,

I'm newbie to Joomla
I would like to edit search module for searching in one category. How could i do that?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to use normal search (com_search) or smart search (com_finder?)

Comment: Normal search. Default com_search find all articles in all categories. I want to edit it for searching in one category. Could you help me? :)

Answer (score 1):

I really doubt that you can do that with com_search.

The basic search is old and outdated, probably it will be soon dropped.

Check Smart Search (com_finder). It has lots of cool features and it may work very well for you.